# C - Get pointer adress to string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to re-code the `printf` function. I'm stuck on the `%p` flag.
As you know, `%p` flag prints the address of a pointer. The problem is that I would like to get this address in a character string (`char *`), in order to print it.
Is there a way to get an address ?

Thank you.

Comment: [`sprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) "prints" to a string

Comment: No, `%p` prints the *value* of a pointer (which is the address of something else). That is, the answer to your question "Is there a way to get an address?" is that the pointer *is* that address.

Comment: `%p` is not a flag, it's a conversion specification.

Comment: Why not simply cast whatever pointer you have to an `uintptr_t`, then print that using the largest unsigned integral conversion (you have %lu implemented already)?

Comment: If you're re-coding `printf`, isn't the point to do the conversion to (hexadecimal)  string yourself rather than relying on library functions?

Comment: The exact character sequence produced by `%p` is implementation dependent. Some implementations will treat a null pointer value as a special case (for example GNU libc on the the system I'm using produces the character sequence `(nil)` for a null pointer value).

Comment: `char *` is *not* a "*character string*". It is a pointer to `char`, nothing more nothing less. To store a "string" an **array** of `char` is needed.

Comment: Strange question for someone who tries to rewrite `printf`.

Comment: The way to get the address is, the caller of the function passes you a parameter, which you extract using VA_ARGS or some other mechanism. The value of the parameter is the address that you're supposed to print. There's nothing magical about a pointer; it's simpler than printing a `float` or `double`.

Comment: 1/ Convert your pointer to a `uintptr_t`. 2/ Print that using the `"%" PRIxPTR` conversion specifier, which will use something like the `%lx` you already implemented.

Comment: Epitech spotted (he's trying to make us do its computer science exercises).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably lost on what is a pointer.

Consider this code: `char *foo = "bar";`

Here, `foo` is a pointer. A pointer is just a variable that holds the address of some space in memory. Here `foo` IS the pointer to the string "bar".
Also, address in memory are not magic, they are themselves a number. So you just need to print the number stored in your variable.

Unrelated, it's not a smart move to post a question about a school project, in your real name, with context. It could allow other students or worse, your administration to find that you did not do your personal projects by yourself.

Comment: Moreover, `char *` just means `a pointer which point to data that should be interpreted as a char`. The char just indicate what is should theorically point to. There is also general pointer type, `void *`.